# Google identity toolkit configuration page broken. How to configure now?

Tags: google-identity-toolkit

Tried to enter the configuration page of Google Identity Toolkit (from gear icon on Google Developers Console), but it directs to a page with only the server and client json templates, but no textBoxes to configure the toolkit.

Some days ago, same gear icon redirected to old google api's console toolkit configuration page.

How can i configure now the toolkit (or change a currently configured one)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This display issue is caused by incomplete OAuth2 client information. Make sure you have set the "Authorized redirect URIs" in ALL your OAuth2 web clients under "Credentials" settings and try again. You can change the URI at any time so if you don't have a redirect URI now, just enter any valid url for testing purpose.

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: I checked this as the solution, since it solves the problem. Although I need to be able to have Web clients defined without needing a redirect URI (for other purposes not to be used by Identity Toolkit).

Comment: Just a follow-up, this issue is fixed now in the Developer Console.